# How to count appearances of a number in a Different sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, multiple-columns

How do I count how many times a number appears in a column, in a *different sheet* than where the formula is.

I can't count it in the same sheet because the first sheet gets sent to people that don't need the count.

Comment: Have you tried `countif`?

Comment: Before you export the worksheet to 'other people', you will have to revert the formula to its result with Copy, Paste Special, Values.

Comment: @findwindow yes its this: COUNTIF(range, criteria) but how would I make it count from a different sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sheet reference. =COUNTIF(Sheet2!A1:A10, criteria)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make it count "A" indefinitely and not just to "A10"?

Comment: I just used A1 to A10 as an example but you can adjust to however large your particular data range is. Personally if it's just a single column my data is in I usually would type up to the =countif( part then go to the sheet with the column, click on the first cell then do shift + control then down button. That should capture your entire range in the formula as long as there are no blank cells.